# Jakarta Mail OAUTH support for Office365 over POP protocol

Tags: jakarta-mail

We are trying to connect to Office365 over POP3 using OAUTH. We get the error "Protocol error. Connection is closed. 10" stacktrace mentioned below

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Protocol error. Connection is closed. 10
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:193)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
```

Below if the snipped of code we are usign to connect

```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true"); 
   props.put("mail.pop3s.auth.mechanisms","XOAUTH2");
   props.put("mail.debug", "true");
   session = Session.getInstance(props);
   final Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
   store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, userId, accessToken);
```

We are able to connect to Office using IMAP protocol over OAUTH. we tried this with jakarta-mail-1.6.5 and jakarta-mail-1.6.6 both but are unable to resolve the error. Please suggest if we are connecting wrongly or there is any properties missing.

Answer (score 1):

Worked with the workaround mentioned in https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/461 on Jakarta-mail 1.6.6 development version.